# What does this mean: "bull queers take by force?"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

In the classic movie *The Shawshank Redemption*, Red says, "Bull queers take by force." What does it mean, and is it an idiom or phrase?

[Movie Quote DB has more context](http://www.moviequotedb.com/movies/shawshank-redemption-the/quote_21149.html):

> **Red**: No? Wait a while. Word gets around. The Sisters have taken quite a likin' to you, especially Bogs.
>   **Andy**: I don't suppose it would help any if I explained to them I'm not homosexual.
>   **Red**: Neither are they. You have to be human first. They don't qualify. *Bull queers take by force.* That's all they want or understand. If I were you, I'd grow eyes in the back of my head.

Answer (score 4):

It is not an idiom. In this context "queer" is slang for a homosexual. A "bull queer" would be a male homosexual who plays only the male role in homosexual encounters and, moreover, implies that the person is aggressive. The phrase refers to groups of prisoners who rape other prisoners.